# Exception raised during rendering: Could not find layout resource matching value 0x7F04001B (resolved name: content_main) in current configuration

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Getting this exception when I created a new project with a new Activity.

> Exception raised during rendering: Could not find layout resource matching value 0x7F04001B (resolved name: content_main) in current configuration.

[image]

When I go into the `content_main`, I do see a proper image and no rendering problems.

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I have been getting the same issues since I updated Android Studio. It seems to be affecting only layouts with include tags in them.

If you go to "File > Invalidate Caches/Restart...", click "Invalidate and Restart", then wait a minute or two wile AS does its thing it should cause them to show up again.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way to get rid of this error.

1. Go to the Project folder where the XML file resides, (in the case of OP's question, this would be the **content_main.xml** file).
2. Rename the file to anything else such as **ren_content_main.xml**.
3. Rebuild the project. The compiler will complain that **ren_content_main.xml** resource does not exist. Ignore these errors.
4. Rename the file back to the original name i.e **content_main.xml**.
5. Rebuild the project again.
6. Watch the error disappear like magic.

Answer (score 1):

go to "File > Invalidate Caches/Restart...", click "Invalidate and Restart",then comment out whole code then remove the comment. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the other answers, I just **cleaned** and **rebuilt** the project, then the error message was gone.

I.e.,

```
Build => Clean Project
Build => Rebuild Project
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately invalidating cache and restart or clean and rebuild did not work for me. So I tried to commit all the changes except the ones in that layout and then stash the change in that layout. Now the layout stopped throwing that error and rendered back to normal. Thankfully I did not make much additions to the layout which was throwing error so I was okay with stashing.

Answer (score 0):

just copy the text highlighted in red and put it in the newly created element (it's empty initially)[image]